# How do I specify a customers default shipping address in a database table?

Tags: mysql, database

Here is a simple example:

Assume I have a customer table that has a one-to-many relationship with the address table (a customer can have multiple shipping addresses but a shipping address can only belong to a single customer).

```
Customer Table
-------------
customer_id (PK)


Address Table
-------------
address_id (PK)
customer_id (FK)
```

Now I want each customer to be able to specify a default shipping address.

I can think of 2 ways but both have drawbacks.

**Option 1**

Add a Boolean column to the Address Table called "is_default".

**Pros**

1. Select queries are simple
2. Straightforward for other people to understand if they see the DB model

**Cons**

1. The application is forced to enforce and maintain the "only one row can be a default" constraint.
2. Updating the default field is a pain because it requires the application to check and reset the previous default option.

**Option 2**

Add a column to the Customer table called "address_id" and make it a foreign key (also allow nulls just in case no address exists).

**Pros**

1. Easy to update the default address if the user decides to change it.
2. Database maintains the "only one row can be a default" constraint.

**Cons**

1. I have to add a new indexed column to the Customers Table every time I decide to add some kind of default metadata.
2. Seems like a hack

My question is, is there a standard way to handle this kind of scenario that I am overlooking? Of course there are other options (maybe creating an EAV default options table?) but I'd prefer to keep it as simple as possible because the change is being made to an existing code base so I don't want to break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (maybe creating an EAV default options table?)

I would do this, especially if you're worried about breaking existing code.

```
Customer_Defaults
------------------------------------
customer_id                          PK, FK -> Customer
default_shipping_address_id          FK -> Address
```

Isn't that tidy? By pulling the whole thing into a separate table, you leave the existing tables alone. If you're using some kind of ORM layer, the object over this new table can be queried for directly, and then you can walk to the Address object. No need to even introduce the new object to the existing Customer or Address objects.

Comment: I thought about that but then I'd have to create a new "defaults table" for every table that requires a default i.e. credit card accounts

Comment: @BillH: Why? There's nothing preventing you from adding another column, `default_credit_card_id`, that points to the Credit_Card table. The name of the table is sufficiently generic to capture *all* defaults for the customer.

Answer (score 0):

When you grow new requirements, think about new tables. Here are two different ways to approach your problem. The first is less stringent than the second. (I would use the second.) I'll assume "Address Table" is named "customer_addresses".

```
create table default_shipping_addresses (
  customer_id integer primary key references customers (customer_id),
  shipping_addr_id integer not null unique references addresses (addr_id)
);

create table default_shipping_addresses (
  customer_id integer primary key references customers (customer_id),
  shipping_addr_id integer not null unique references addresses (addr_id),

  -- Add a UNIQUE constraint on customer_addresses (customer_id, address_id).
  -- Since address_id is the primary key, it's unique, so (customer_id, 
  -- address_id) will also be unique. But you need the UNIQUE constraint to
  -- allow a foreign key to reliably reference it, even in MySQL.
  foreign key (customer_id, shipping_addr_id) 
    references customer_addresses (customer_id, address_id)
);
```

Comment: Couldn't I just make a compound primary key between the customer_id and shipping_addr_id with 2 foreign keys pointing to their respective sources?